# IDEA 13.0.2 + Scala Plugin 0.30.387 : CPU peaks at each keystroke, but only on Windows, not on Mac

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, cpu-usage

[image]

The picture above shows how four (!) 3GHz cores are maxed out every time I press space in the editor of IntelliJ 13.0.2 when editing a Scala file. This makes IDEA very unresponsive.

This happens on Windows 7. I also work on the same project on a Mac, using the same IDEA version and I have no problem there.  I tried to increase already the memory heap, it did not help.

Any suggestions?

EDIT:

- I disabled the hg4idea plugin -> it did not help.
- I disabled the SBT plugin -> it did not help.

EDIT 2:

I tried 13.1EAP, now the situation got better (see image below). Peaks belong to keystrokes.

[image]

Comment: Yes, try new EAP, and report it. http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA

Comment: Ok, I will link to this question.

Comment: I sent it to https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/home

Comment: It's simple - do not use Windows!